# domain redirection is not working from old to new

Tags: htaccess

I have 2 domains running in parallel say abc.com and xyz.com. Here our company has decided to change the abc.com to some new branding xyz.com. so for that we have taken the entire content from the abc.com server and hosted new website xyz.com with same content and we have successfully redirected abc.com to xyz.com without any trouble. But the internal pages of abc.com/about, abc.com/contact etc are not redirecting. This entire is hosted with wordpress. I have tried with some online tutorials with .htaccess tricks. Nothing works for me.

Here one thing need to notice is both abc.com and xyz.com are running in parallel. Means if you open abc.com then it redirects perfectly to xyz.com but if i open abc.com with their internal pages then its not redirecting. So my question is do i need to completely remove the abc.com and its content and database from the server or it can be managed with simple .htaccess tricks.

Please let me know the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on WordPress.stack exchange.com, not here. The answer is likely that you need to GI through the database and update all references of ABC.com to xyz.com. There are plugins to do this for the database (or you can use wp CLI search-replace). You may also need to go throughnth theme and search and replace across the files.

Comment: How have you currently implemented the redirect?

Comment: @MrWhite, No i havent tried yet.

Comment: Then why did you state, "we have **successfully redirected** abc.com to xyz.com without any trouble"? What do you mean by that? Please show what you have tried with `.htaccess` and what happened exactly. To confirm... if you access the site via `xyz.com` (the _new_ domain) then it works as intended?

Comment: I will move to wordpress, but please know a lot of documents on how to do it can be found there; https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/